# WebDriver: want to get the child elements of an element created using@FindBy

Tags: java, selenium

I am using `Page Factory` and I have 2 radio buttons(male and female), both of the radio buttons have the name locator as common, `name='radl'`, additionally 'value' of male radio button='m' and female radio button is 'f'. I need to select any one of these radio buttons based on user input.How do I get the child elements of the below "gender" element?

```
@FindBy(name ="radl")
WebElement gender;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the genders into two webelements. Click the one you want.

```
@FindBy(css ="input[name='radl'][value='m']")
WebElement maleGender;

@FindBy(css ="input[name='radl'][value='f']")
WebElement femaleGender;
```

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to get child elements of 'gender' webelement that i created?

Comment: Yeah use the @FindBys (note the plural) and pass in an array of FindBy annotations. @FindBys({@FindBy(id = "foo"), @FindBy(className = "bar")}) in this case element 'bar' will be returned if it appears under the hierarchy of element 'foo'. You can also use a css or xpath to get this.